# Problems with Facebook's SSO on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make an app for android using facebook's SSO, so first i made a test app to test their api.

I've been following the Android starting tutorial [here on the facebook dev site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/). All was working well. When the app got started it would let me sign into facebook using its traditional webview login (since facebook wasn't installed on the emulator). Then i noticed that if you have facebook already installed then it would use a more fancy screen to log in.

So i installed facebook, opened the app, all went well. Closed and reopened the app and the facebook reauthorize screen popped up but this time with no info on it..

[image]

Which is abit odd... so when i click on 'Ok' this shows up..

[image]

so if i click 'ok' again it just opens facebook in a browser.
If this something to do with my code? Or something on Facebook's side? I have the same problem on both an emulator and a real device. The emulator was running facebooks dev app which came with the sdk, and the device has the latest facebook app from the android market.

The code is here..

```
public class Home extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("Blanked the ID :)");
String FILENAME = "app_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if (access_token != null) facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    if (expires != 0) facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable the enhanced auth dialog [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) after you choose your application

App settings-> Advanced Settings -> Enhanced Auth Dialog: Disabled

Cheers.